# variable keeps returning NULL, php

Tags: php, zend-framework, sendmail

```
protected $_name = 'usertable';  //table name for database [Impt] Please change accordingly
protected $_temp;       

function resetPass($userid)
{
    $pass = new Application_Model_Register();
    $salt = $pass->generateSalt();
    $temp = $pass->generatePass();
    $this->_temp = (string) $temp;


    $data = array(
            'password' => hash("sha256", ($salt. $temp)),
            'salt' => $salt, //get salt from generateSalt()
    );

    //$auth= Zend_Auth::getInstance(); //declare zend_auth to get instance
    //$user= $auth->getIdentity(); //get identity of user
    //$userid   = $user->userid; //get userid of user

    echo $temp;


    $this->update($data, 'userid = '. (int)($userid));
    return $this;
}

function getTemp()
{
    return parent::$this->_temp;
}
```

This is my code in Model. I am trying to return $_temp therefore I made  $this->temp = $temp. My problem is that it returns NULL.

```
public function sendEmail($email)
{

    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $userid = '30';

    $reset = new Application_Model_DbTable_Register();
    $reset->resetPass($userid);

    $pswd = new Application_Model_DbTable_Register();
    $pswd = $pswd->getTemp();
    var_dump($pswd);

    $mail = new Zend_Mail();

    $mail->setFrom('swap.test@yahoo.com.sg', 'Inexorable Beauty');
    $mail->addTo($email, $email);
    $mail->setSubject('Inexorable Beauty: Password Reset');
    $mail->setBodyText('Dear Customer,

            You have requested to reset your password.
            This is the temporary password: '.$pswd.'

            Please log in immediately and change your password.
            Thank You.

            Yours Sincerely,
            Inexorable Beauty');

    $mail->send();

    if($mail->send())
    {
        echo "Email successfully sent!";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Email was not sent";
    }



}
```

This is my controller code. I am trying to send the temporary passwd to the customer's email. I call the getTemp() function from my model to get the passwd string but as you can see I did var_dump($pswd) and it keeps returning NULL. Any solutions?

Comment: Thanks guys. I added a global in front of $_temp and it works fine. Seems like the variable couldnt be used outside of the function. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 1):

You're using

```
 return parent::$this->_temp;
```

Does `$_temp` exist in the parent object? It would appear you're definining it in THIS object, and it doesn't exist in the parent object you're (hopefully) inheriting from.

Comment: Removed the parent. I returned $this->_temp, still gives me NULL.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are creating two `DbTable_Register` objects, calling reset on the first one, but not the second, and then you are trying to get the temp password from the second object.  The second one wont have temp because you have not called `resetPass` on the second object.

Try changing:

```
$reset = new Application_Model_DbTable_Register();
$reset->resetPass($userid);

$pswd = new Application_Model_DbTable_Register();
$pswd = $pswd->getTemp();
var_dump($pswd);
```

To:

```
$reset = new Application_Model_DbTable_Register();
$reset->resetPass($userid);
$pswd  = $reset->getTemp();

var_dump($pswd);
```

See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

**First** : Check **Application_Model_Register::generatePass();** function

**Second** : on resetPass function remove this:

```
$this->_temp = (string) $temp;
```

and add :

```
if (empty($temp)){
    $this->_temp = (string) $temp;
}
```

is it return **a value of something?** If it doesn't then the *generatePass()* function is **wrong**.

**Third** : on Your controller

```
$reset = new Application_Model_DbTable_Register();
$reset->resetPass($userid);
$pswd = new Application_Model_DbTable_Register();
$pswd = $pswd->getTemp();
var_dump($pswd);
```

don't make a double object like **$reset** and **$pswd**.

try to :

```
$reset = new Application_Model_DbTable_Register();
$pswd = $reset->resetPass($userid)->getTemp();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($pswd);
```

correct me if i'm wrong.